# Блокирование файла сессии Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, сессия, redis

В проекте на Laravel 7 иногда вываливается ошибка `upstream timed out (110: Unknown error) while reading response header from upstream`
Сам сайт отдает  при этом ошибку 504.
Перебирая пошагово на каком этапе возникает проблема, пришел к тому, что в  Middleware StartSession есть такая проверка на доступность сессии:

```
$session = $this->getSession($request);
if ($this->manager->shouldBlock() || ($request->route() && $request->route()->locksFor())) {
   return $this->handleRequestWhileBlocking($request, $session, $next);
} else {
   return $this->handleStatefulRequest($request, $session, $next);
}
```

Если изменить драйвер на Coockie, то проблема пропадает, но использовать куки в качестве хранилища не вариант, как и БД. Проблема возникает если использовать в качестве драйвера и  file и redis. Есть ли какое-то решение этой проблемы?